# Azure Dynamic Email Notification to user Who uploaded the file to SFTP Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have question about Azure Notification email, for example Azure have 2 users only

- Alex@sample.com and Albert@sample.com

1. FILE ABC.csv uploaded by alex@sample.com to sftp azure, and when done processing piplein the notification will only sent to alex@sample.com only. Albert will not received the email.

is it possible to do it on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using **`Azure Function`** & **`Azure Logic App`**

Here I am using the Azure Logic App:
Create a **Logic App** with ***Consumption Plan*** & click the **Blank Logic App**

Search **SFTP** connector in Search Bar
[image]

Click any one of the above Triggers and Add **SFTP** details in a trigger.

[image]

After adding your **SFTP** details try to add the **Office Outlook 365** connector.

Add Alex@sample.com and Albert@sample.com to address and add the **Added/Modified File** details in a body and subject.
[image]

Refer [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-emails-csharp-dotnet-with-azure-functions-and-sendgrid-bindings) for **Send Emails in Azure Function** using **SendGrid**.

Comment: what if i have lists users 100 email, and they uploaded randomly, and  who uploaded the file will rececive the notification, and the 99 others will not receive